# Regarding use of callback function

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I have read callbacks are used for event handlers or in asynchronous codes where we are not sure of the response, but my question is very simple that should I use callback when I have a function to be used in another function?

For example:

```
let name = function () {
  return "Umar"
}

let printName = function () {
    return name()
}

console.log(printName())
```

But in the below code, I am trying to pass as a callback function, and returns synatx error. Can I use callbacks here for this case, also it is returning error.

```
let name = function () {
  return "Umar"
}

let printName = function (name) {
  return name()
}

console.log(printName())
Also I have another problem, Look at this code it is thrwoing an error for the variable to be not defined, however I have defined it
let name = function () {
  return "Umar"
}

let printName = function () {
    let name = name()
    return name
}

console.log(printName())
```

However. naming varaible name as name1 in the second function works fine, for example

```
let name = function () {
  return "Umar"
}

let printName = function () {
    let name1 = name()
    return name1
}

console.log(printName())
```

Why the name variable is throwing error even after I have defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is when you pass one function as an argument to another. **You never do this**.

In one place you almost do this:

> ```
> let printName = function (name) {
>   return name()
> }
> ```

Above you are written a function which calls the first argument it gets as a function.

However when you then call the function:

> ```
> console.log(printName())
> ```

… you **don't** pass any arguments!

Consequently, `name` is undefined and the function throws an exception.

> Why the name variable is throwing error even after I have defined it.

You declared `name` twice. Once in the global scope (where you assigned it a function) and again in the scope of the `printName` function (where you assigned it `undefined`).

> should I use callback when I have a function to be used in another function?

Not as a general case. You use a callback when you have a function that needs to call different functions at different times.

Comment: Yes I did a mistake. I should have passed the argument in the last function, but I forgot to pass it. Regarding the name variable. I am once declaring in global scope and another in a local scope, I am still doubtful in this case. However your anwer was great. Thank you.